# Prevent NetworkManager from storing WiFi connections and passwords for all users by default

Tags: networkmanager

It seems that, by default, NetworkManager stores WiFi connections and passwords under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` so that they are available for all users. How can this be disabled? I know I can configure this for each connection separately, but how can I disable it entirely or so that it's not the default behavior for any new connections? I want each user to have privacy so that other users don't see to which WiFis some other users have connected and, in particular, they shouldn't be able to use the passwords other users have used.

What makes it even worse is that when connecting to a WiFi network, NetworkManager doesn't even ask if I want to store the connection information and password for all users. It does that without asking.

To me, the current behavior seems like a very weird default. Storing passwords so that other users can use them too doesn't sound like a good default behavior.